# List of conflicts humans can have

Tags: conflict

I am searching a list of conflicts humans can have.

Here I found some [7 types of conflicts](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/types_of_conflict_in_literature.en.html)

- Person vs Person
- Person vs self
- Person vs. Fate/God(s)
- Person vs. Nature
- Person vs. Society
- Person vs. the Unknown/Extraterrestrial
- Person vs. Technology/Machinery

But the refer to literature, not to psychology.

This wikipedia page contains a list: [Conflicts (Social science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict#Social_science) But this is just a list of unrelated articles.

Is there a valuable book/article which provides an overview over the different conflicts humans can have?

Comment: I don't see any value to having a list like this. Maybe you can convince me otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to a list, if there is anything like that it is simply internal and external conflicts (which encompasses your list, as well as deals with overlapping components of your list).

Furthermore, there are three major paradigms of sociology, one of which is conflict theory. This examines stratification (ie through classes) and inequality (ie of resources), largely being credited to Karl Marx. In general, the paradigms are different lenses with which to examine issues in society (gender, class, race, etc.).